# ul or nav for breadcrumbs in HTML?

Tags: semantics, zurb-foundation, semantic-web, semantic-markup, breadcrumbs

The Foundation front-end framework provides [2 ways of representing breadcrumbs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/breadcrumbs.html) in HTML:

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
  <li class="unavailable"><a href="#">Gene Splicing</a></li>
  <li class="current"><a href="#">Cloning</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this way with `nav` and `a` elements instead of `ul` and `li`:

```
<nav class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Features</a>
  <a class="unavailable" href="#">Gene Splicing</a>
  <a class="current" href="#">Cloning</a>
</nav>
```

Which way is semantically more appropriate?

Comment: I think both are semantically correct. In the specification, examples using the `<nav>` element have the structure of `<nav><ul><li><a></a></li></ul></nav>`

Comment: @Zenith - any good reasons to believe one of them is **more** semantically correct than the other?

Comment: Well, the majority of examples using <nav> on the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) uses unordered lists and list elements to contain navigation anchors, so I'd go with that. Not to say the other way is less semantically correct (I think both are equal), but that's just what I'd go for.

Comment: I’d say this should be two questions: 1. use `nav` or not? 2. Use `ul` or not? You could certainly use `nav` in your first example (around the `ul`) and you could certainly omit `nav` in your second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crumbs are used for marking, so they are marks instead of list items. Therefore from the viewpoint of semantics, the second way is the correct approach.

== 2021-08-26 Update ==

Please note that Schema.org [recommends](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList) using ordered list. I once discussed this thing with a person who understands accessibility, and I was informed that screen readers announce the amount of list items when they access a list, so using list in this situation is useful for screen reader users to know the amount of crumbs a breadcrumb navigation has.

Comment: The bit BETWEEN each link is a mark, if it exists, but the main bit is an ordered list of links.

Comment: @MikeBrockington It depends on how one views a breadcrumb navigation. Anyway, I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Use This SCHEMA strcture**

**

> Use this for Microdata for breadcrumber

**

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ul>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" class="home" >
      <a href="index.html" title="Go to Home Page" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Home</span>
      </a>
      <span>></span>
    </li>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" class="category5">
      <a href="product.html" title="Product" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">product name</span>
      </a>
      <span>></span>
    </li>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" class="category5">
      <a href=".finalproduct.html" title="final product" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">final product</span>
      </a>
      <span>></span>
    </li>
    <li class="category6"><strong>Final Product view</strong></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**

> Important: It also used for **SEO Purpose** in **search engine** like google,yahoo for displaying efficient in it...

**

[enter link description here](https://schema.org/breadcrumb)

Answer (score 0):

schema.org recommends using the following scheme https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList

```
<ol itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses">
    <span itemprop="name">Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  </li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses/real">
    <span itemprop="name">Real Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
  </li>
</ol>
```